# PHP SimpleXML: how to prevent converting > into &gt;

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following XML-structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<node>text text >>>>> text</node>
</root>
```

When I load this string using `simplexml_load_string` and output by `print_r()` I get the result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [node] => text text >>>>> text
)
```

Everything is ok. But problems begans when I convert my SimpleXMLElement to string using `asXML()` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<node>text text &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; text</node>
</root>
```

As you can see - `>` characters was converted into `&gt;`

How to prevent this converting?

Comment: Why do you care? The XML means the same thing.

Comment: Well, your initial XML structure is not a valid XML. SimpleXML only makes the output valid.

Comment: This is important for me.

Comment: Is it important to you to get a non-well-formed XML?

Comment: If the structure was not valid, SimpleXML would not throw an exception?

Comment: @AndrewAndrew: My bad, it turns out that you can actually use `>` inside a node content... SimpleXML probably just escapes it in the output just to be sure...

Comment: @AndrewAndrew — Was "This is important for me" a response to "Why do you care?"? Because that's just recursion. You can't care just because you care. Why does this matter at all?

Comment: @Quentin - yes. In my case I need to save original entities look

Comment: @AndrewAndrew — Why? The XML means the same thing. You keep restating your desire to do this, but you never explain your reasons.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. SimpleXML (and libxml underneath it) is not designed to retain the exact human-readable representation of the underlying XML, only the machine-readable structure; parsing and re-serialization is always likely to lose some "insignificant" details like this.

Answer (score -1):

You could use html_entity_decode like this:

```
html_entity_decode(asXML($string))
```

Comment: Node content might contain entities that I don't need to decode.